# Fonts are not loading in webpack build

Tags: javascript, webpack

The fonts are not rendering on the browser when it seems like the build process worked just fine. Webpack is correctly moving the font files to `public/fonts` directory. The built css files are showing the correct path to the font file.

Here is the loaders configuration:

```
{
    test: /\.s?css$/,
    loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'sass?sourceMap']
},
{
    test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)/,
    loader: 'file?name=../fonts/[name].[ext]'
},
{
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
    loader: "url-loader?limit=100000"
}
```

Here is the build output:

```
                                     Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
                    ../fonts/icon_set_2.svg  20.9 kB          [emitted]
  ../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot  20.1 kB          [emitted]
 ../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff  23.4 kB          [emitted]
  ../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf  45.4 kB          [emitted]
  ../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg   109 kB          [emitted]
                    ../fonts/icon_set_1.eot  71.6 kB          [emitted]
                   ../fonts/icon_set_1.woff  41.9 kB          [emitted]
                    ../fonts/icon_set_1.ttf  71.5 kB          [emitted]
                    ../fonts/icon_set_1.svg  98.5 kB          [emitted]
                    ../fonts/icon_set_2.eot  13.9 kB          [emitted]
                   ../fonts/icon_set_2.woff  7.85 kB          [emitted]
                    ../fonts/icon_set_2.ttf  13.7 kB          [emitted]
../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2    18 kB          [emitted]
                      ../fonts/fontello.eot   533 kB          [emitted]
                     ../fonts/fontello.woff   321 kB          [emitted]
                      ../fonts/fontello.ttf   532 kB          [emitted]
                      ../fonts/fontello.svg   826 kB          [emitted]
                      ../fonts/Glyphter.eot  7.22 kB          [emitted]
                     ../fonts/Glyphter.woff  5.02 kB          [emitted]
                      ../fonts/Glyphter.ttf  7.06 kB          [emitted]
                      ../fonts/Glyphter.svg  45.2 kB          [emitted]
                             main.bundle.js   1.2 MB       0  [emitted]  main
                           vendor.bundle.js  3.74 MB       1  [emitted]  vendor
                         main.bundle.js.map  1.72 MB       0  [emitted]  main
                       vendor.bundle.js.map  5.58 MB       1  [emitted]  vendor
```

This is from the bootstrap file that the browser is receiving,:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

  src: url(/../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot);
  src: url(/../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'), url(/../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2) format('woff2'), url(/../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff) format('woff'), url(/../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf) format('truetype'), url(/../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular) format('svg');
}
```

And this is the directory structure of the public directory

```
+ public
    + build
        main.bundle.js
        vendor.bundle.js
    + fonts
        glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
        rest of font files...
```

But when I try to use the fonts (glyphicons), they don't render correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but you can't use a relative path for the fonts. I was experiencing the exact same issue and my work around was to put the fonts in a folder under the "build" directory. So your directory structure would look like this:

```
+ public
    + build
        main.bundle.js
        vendor.bundle.js
        + fonts
            glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
            rest of font files...
```

Here's what my loaders look like:

```
{
    test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff&name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
},
{
    test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)?$/,
    loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
},
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
},
```

Also note that as of Webpack 2.0 you should use the *-loader version for all loaders, as in my example.

Hope that helps.